# Symfony 3 MicroKernel and db connection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I want to create a symfony app with MicroKernelTrait. I have problem with doctrine and creating query.

I use this example(single file):
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/micro_kernel_trait.html

How i should configure db(separate file or not) and which bundles I need?

PS. I will be grateful for the simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to install [`DoctrineBundle`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle), then register and configure it:

```
$ composer require doctrine/doctrine-bundle
```

```php
//index.php
//…
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    //…
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        return array(
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle()
        );
    }
    //…
    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $c, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        //…
        // in-file config
        $c->loadFromExtension('doctrine', array(
            'dbal' => array(
                'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => null,
                'dbname' => 'symfony',
                'user' => 'root',
                'password' => 'Pa$$w0rd',
                'charset' => 'UTF8'
            )
        ));
        // or from-file config
        // $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/doctrine.yml');
    }
}
```

After that, you can access Doctrine by `$this->container->get('doctrine');`.

Comment: When i try get menager from dotrine $this->container->get('doctrine')->getMenager(); Get 'Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist.'

Comment: @mcek if you need ORM just install it: `$ composer require doctrine/orm`